# Is it posible to make a MySQL SELECT query that does change records if they repeat?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, window-functions

I have very simple query that gets me list of names:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `names` WHERE (...)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Steven
David
Matt
David
George
Steven
Steven
David
Matt
```

Yet I'd like to diverse those names by adding there a number for each independent name that does repeat itself, so the output would look like this:

```
Steven 1
David 1
Matt 1
David 2
George
Steven 2
Steven 3
David 3
Matt 2
```

It would be perfect in this case, if George would not get the number, since this name does not repeat. Is it possible to make a query that would alter the output in this way, or am I forced to do this later in PHP?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select name, row_number() over(partition by name order by id) rn
from names
```

This assumes that you have a column called `id` that can be used to uniquely identify each row (that could be a set of column as well), which is needed to get a stable result.

In earlier versions, one option uses a correlated subquery (but it does not scale well if you have a lot of rows):

```
select name,
    (select 1 + count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.name = t.name and t1.id < t.id) rn
from mytable t
```

Comment: This assumes too much, I fear.

Comment: @Strawberry what assumptions are you unsure about?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't want a number for "George", so you need some conditional logic:

```
select name,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by name) > 1
             then row_number() over (partition by name)
        end)
from . . .
where . . .;
```